# Время реакции на вопросы

Tags: обсуждение, вопросы, ответы, статистика

Попалась сегодня такая [юморная картинка](https://t.me/math_and_physics2013/3511) (ниже), которая навела на серьезные размышления: а каково на самом деле среднее (и распределение заодно) время реакции на (отвеченный, видимо.... неотвеченные просто выпадают из статистики) вопрос?

Кто хорошо в SQL и SO ориентируется, никто не пробовал такую статистику снять? По ответам и комментариям? Интересно было бы посмотреть...

[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

Comment: смотря что считать реакцией. Просто наличие ответа ведь - ничего не показывает, в нем может быть и дополнение к вопросу от самого автора, например.

Comment: @Grundy Это время реакции сообщества на вопросы. "Может быть" и "статистически значимо" — это все же две большие разницы...

Comment: На мой взгляд - это как средняя температура по больнице. Существуют темы/тэги по которым либо нет знающих людей, либо очень мало и соответственно все вопросы по этой тематике быдут "ждунами"...

Comment: @XelaNimed OK, вы можете сделать с разбивкой по тегам?

Comment: Не знаю, как тут, но на enSO если не ответят быстро или вскоре после правки, то весьма вероятно, что не ответят вообще.

Comment: напрямую зависит от популярности метки и от количества активных участников, компетентных в данном вопросе....а подобную статистику мне бы тоже было интересно посмотреть

Comment: Ладно, все понятно. Когда не получается сделать, идут рассуждения о том, почему это не имеет смысла :)

Comment: @Qwertiy Так оно и есть, но что значит "быстро" в количественном выражении? Теперь я знаю...

Comment: @Grundy У вас есть уникальный вопрос с "самоответом" (см. P.P.S. в моем ответе) — расскажите, как у вас это получилось? :)

Comment: @Harry, час, максимум несколько часов)

Answer (score 16, accepted):

Хочешь что-то получить — сделай это сам :)

Итак, по моим любимым `c` и `c++` разброс во времени получения первого (не обязательно принятого) ответа вышел замечательно широким: от 0 до практически 10 лет, так что среднее значение получилось около 10 дней с куда большей дисперсией.

Ноль — это "самоответы", неинтересно, как и ответы через 10 лет :)

Поэтому я решил ограничиться ответами, в которых время ответа строго больше нуля, но меньше 3 дней, и посмотреть на них. Оказалось, что таких ответов больше 94%, так что 3 дня я счел вполне адекватным выбором.

Теперь среднее значение стало около 14000 секунд, но со среднеквадратичным отклонением в 32000, так что я решил не мучиться и посмотреть на гистограмму...

Вот она, с "корзинками" по минуте:

[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

Наконец-то что-то стало различимо, так что я по вечернему времени долго не мучился, а обрубил все вопросы, которые не привлекли ничье внимание 12 часов, и получил, что их все равно огромное количество - 85%.

Среднее значения и для них оставалось неприлично неточным, так что я просто построил новую гистограмму и на этом остановился.

Вот она, с "корзинками" по 5 минут:

[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

В принципе, я узнал, что хотел. Что подавляющее большинство вопросов получают первый ответ (если получают его вообще) в пределах 15 минут, ну, а если ответ не получен в течение нескольких часов, то шансы получить его становятся призрачными.

Итак, мужик на картинке в вопросе зря так затосковал, шансы получить ответ все еще достаточно высоки :). Но если заменить 1 минуту на 10 — то его грусть становится вполне понятной. Если, конечно, он задал вопрос по C/C++ на ruSO...

P.S. Я не статистик, не data scientist, так что очевидный мне самому дилетантизм можно в комментариях не особо подчеркивать. Но если кто-то захочет заметить что-то по сути и дать свое заключение — будет очень интересно почитать.

P.P.S. Замечу, что есть интересный [вопрос](https://ru.stackoverflow.com/q/626264/195342), который был задан `10 фев 2017 в 15:29`, а ответ на него дан `4 фев 2017 в 19:15` (и такой "досрочный" ответ не один). Как получилось это нарушение причинно-следственных связей и пространственно-временного континуума — вопрос не ко мне, самому интересно...

P.P.P.S. Гистограмма для C#

[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

Для `python`

[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

P.P.P.P.S. Для C/C++ распределение среднего времени отклика от оценки вопроса. Действительно, в целом не представляющие особого интереса вопросы получают ответы дольше.

[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

В трехмерном виде (так сказать, издалека и укрупненно)...

[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

Comment: В физике есть эффект наблюдателя... мне кажется, что если изъять эффект, который наблюдатель внес в данную статистику, то могут получиться совершенно другие цифры))) Так что можно добавить еще распрелеление без ваших ответов :-) так будет честнее :-)

Comment: Интересно бы на шарп посмотреть...

Comment: При объединении вопросов, ответы переносятся в один. Первый [вопрос](https://ru.stackoverflow.com/questions/623285/%d0%9f%d0%be%d1%87%d0%b5%d0%bc%d1%83-%d0%b1%d1%8b%d1%81%d1%82%d1%80%d0%b5%d0%b5-%d0%be%d0%b1%d1%80%d0%b0%d0%b1%d0%be%d1%82%d0%b0%d1%82%d1%8c-%d0%be%d1%82%d1%81%d0%be%d1%80%d1%82%d0%b8%d1%80%d0%be%d0%b2%d0%b0%d0%bd%d0%bd%d1%8b%d0%b9-%d0%bc%d0%b0%d1%81%d1%81%d0%b8%d0%b2-%d1%87%d0%b5%d0%bc-%d0%bd%d0%b5%d1%81%d0%be%d1%80%d1%82%d0%b8%d1%80%d0%be%d0%b2%d0%b0%d0%bd%d0%bd%d1%8b%d0%b9?noredirect=1&lq=1) был задан раньше

Comment: Скорее всего, все такие варианты (ответ раньше вопроса) связаны с объединенными вопросами :-)

Comment: Понятно, что большинство вопросов тут "детские". А если взять не все вопросы, а получившие, скажем, 2 и больше плюсов?

Comment: @avp, количество плюсов, к сожалению, далеко не всегда отражает "недетскость" вопроса...по моим наблюдениям наоборот, чем сложнее вопрос и ответ, тем меньше пользователей могут их оценить и тем меньше плюсов они получают... исключение составляют только какие-то совершенно академические и хорошо знакомые темы... так то иногда пишешь статью несколько суток выверяя все до мелочей и проводя исследования - и тебе никто плюсика не поставит и наоборот...пойдешь на какую-то банальную вещь по `javascript'у` ответишь и моментально набежит толпа хомячков и наставит тебе плюсов по самые уши.

Comment: @Grundy Такой вопрос был только один.

Comment: @aepot Добавил гистограмму для `c#`. По "трехсуточным" ответам среднее время немного больше — 6300 с против 5250 для c/c++.

Comment: @МихаилРебров, насчет "детскости" согласен. Но ведь интересно узнать, зависит ли распределение времени первого ответа от конечной оценки вопроса

Comment: @avp Нарисовал и такое... Я правильно понял ваше пожелание?

Comment: @Harry, думаю, да. Только я никак не соображу как новые данные согласуются с предыдущей гистограммой. В предыдущей мы видим, что подавляющее большинство вопросов получало ответ меньше чем за 100 мин, а в новой все вопросы с оценками от -5 до +10 попадают в интервал больше 120 мин. Мне как-то станно что большинство вопросов оцениваются вне  -5:+10 голосов. Наверное, я что-то в этих графиках неверно трактую

Comment: @avp Дело в усреднении. Я сначала пробовал все точки построить, получился забор из линий. Просто очень уж большой разброс получается для каждой оценки, так что некоего "облака" точек не получается. Но, не будучи специалистом в статистике, данных и тем паче их визуализации, я не нашел тот способ представления, который бы учел еще и то, что для каждой оценки есть очень большое количество самых разнообразных времен отклика. Если есть идеи — давайте пробовать их реализовать :) SQL-запрос я могу показать, затем я полученные данные допиливаю своей программой, а визуализирую в Wolfram.

Comment: @Harry, я сейчас понял, что эти графики "о разном". Первый -- это количество вопросов, на которые ответили в интервале времени. А второй -- среднее время ответа для разных оценок вопроса. То самое среднее, что для всех составляет 14000 сек (о чем вы в самом начале пишете). Понятно, что в разбивке по оценкам график №1 становится трехмерным. Можно попробовать сделать несколько графиков №1 (двумерных, т.е. как вы делали) для разных интервалов оценок. Скажем < -5; -5:-1; 0; 1-5; 5-10; > 10.

Comment: @avp Ну, чтоб не мелочиться :) — сразу трехмерная картинка. Так лучше? честно говоря, ожидал лучшего, но...

Comment: @Harry, imho это шикарно. Не ожидал, что она такая симметричная. Тут уже, похоже, исследования каких-то психологов нужны -)

Comment: @avp Нет, все же вправо — в положительные значения оценки — размах чуть шире...

Comment: а каким инструментом рисовали 3д графики?

Comment: @tym32167 См. выше в моем комментарии — **а визуализирую в Wolfram**.

Comment: @Harry спасибо!

Comment: Вы задали вопрос 22 сентября и сами ответили на него 23 сентября)))

Было бы очень интересно узнать цифры по ответам. Ситуация, когда ты ответил, но ни лайка, ни коммента, ни дизлайка ни отмечение решением нет. Никакой реакции. Так же по JS бы глянуть...